# Mean value of all columns for each row in R

Tags: r, row, mean

I need to find the mean value for each row in my dataframes. I'm trying to use the rowMeans-function, but instead of the mean for each row, R produces values incrementally, it looks like this.

```
> df
    row        a        b        c        d        e
1     1 0.116336634 0.148883375 0.332530120 0.002421308 0.387096774
2     2 0.032178218 0.200992556 0.277108434 0.002421308 0.012406948
3     3 0.007425743 0.004962779 0.002409639 0.002421308 0.007444169
4     4 0.007425743 0.004962779 0.004819277 0.004842615 0.009925558
5     5 0.007425743 0.004962779 0.004819277 0.002421308 0.012406948
6     6 0.007425743 0.004962779 0.004819277          NA 0.012406948
7     7 0.007425743 0.004962779 0.004819277 0.002421308 0.009925558
8     8 0.007425743 0.004962779 0.004819277          NA 0.012406948
9     9 0.007425743 0.004962779 0.004819277          NA 0.012406948
10   10 0.007425743 0.004962779 0.007228916 0.004842615 0.012406948
11   11 0.007425743 0.004962779 0.007228916 0.002421308 0.012406948
12   12 0.007425743 0.004962779 0.002409639          NA 0.007444169
13   13 0.007425743 0.004962779 0.002409639          NA 0.007444169
14   14 0.007425743 0.004962779          NA          NA 0.007444169
15   15 0.007425743 0.004962779          NA          NA 0.007444169

df$mean <- rowMeans(df, na.rm = TRUE)
df
> df
    row        a        b        c        d        e        mean
1     1 0.116336634 0.148883375 0.332530120 0.002421308 0.387096774   0.3312114
2     2 0.032178218 0.200992556 0.277108434 0.002421308 0.012406948   0.4208512
3     3 0.007425743 0.004962779 0.002409639 0.002421308 0.007444169   0.5041106
4     4 0.007425743 0.004962779 0.004819277 0.004842615 0.009925558   0.6719960
5     5 0.007425743 0.004962779 0.004819277 0.002421308 0.012406948   0.8386727
6     6 0.007425743 0.004962779 0.004819277          NA 0.012406948   1.2059229
7     7 0.007425743 0.004962779 0.004819277 0.002421308 0.009925558   1.1715924
8     8 0.007425743 0.004962779 0.004819277          NA 0.012406948   1.6059229
9     9 0.007425743 0.004962779 0.004819277          NA 0.012406948   1.8059229
10   10 0.007425743 0.004962779 0.007228916 0.004842615 0.012406948   1.6728112
11   11 0.007425743 0.004962779 0.007228916 0.002421308 0.012406948   1.8390743
12   12 0.007425743 0.004962779 0.002409639          NA 0.007444169   2.4044485
13   13 0.007425743 0.004962779 0.002409639          NA 0.007444169   2.6044485
14   14 0.007425743 0.004962779          NA          NA 0.007444169   3.5049582
15   15 0.007425743 0.004962779          NA          NA 0.007444169   3.7549582
16   16 0.007425743 0.004962779          NA          NA 0.007444169   4.0049582
```

What is my mistake and how can I calculate the  mean value for each row?
I tried to do the same also with the matrix, with the same result.

Comment: You should exclude column `row` from your calculations, i.e. `rowMeans(df[, -1], na.rm = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

One posible soloution is to use the `apply` function. Here is some example data:

```
df <- data.frame(a=rnorm(10),
                 b=rnorm(10))
```

and use the `apply` function on it:

```
apply(df, 1, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```